# Firebase - Query by existence of a (grand)child

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data path like this

```
events
    -KntTJCVBtbrb79dHemC
        dateStamp: 1498747689858
        admin: "rPxwIzEtJaRbEH6ujkP5QJgpHDp2"
        attending:
            rPxwIzEtJaRbEH6ujkP5QJgpHDp2: true
            MtaPwHEKMEOTXBRdXBuXuS3gst12: false
```

I would like to get the events that have certain users attending. In other words, I would like to **get all events where the key "attending/[some-user-id]" exists**.

Problem is I have only been able to do it by filtering by a specific value of that path (either true or false), like this:

```
eventsRef.orderByChild("attending/" + user.getId()).equalTo(true).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

That works but only for where the value of the key is true, so to get what I need I have to do 2 calls, one for when the value is true and one for when it is false.

I tried using **startAt(true)** and **endAt(false)** (and viceversa) but that ended up returning nothing.

I'm not sure what I am missing.

**EDIT**

I should have specified that I know this could be done with denormalization and using another node as the relationship 'table', I was just wondering if the above specifically was possible since it is already so close and it would avoid a 2-step process of getting a key first and then retrieving the actual data.

Comment: you can only query 1 layer deep, you will have to change structure.

Comment: I'm not sure that is true. As you can see from my post, querying using the grandchild's value works, it's just that I care about the key existing, not what value it has.

Answer (score 2):

Here's when denormalisation of data comes into play!

What you described is the only method to query a grandchild. And of course, as you mentioned, it is not very intuitive, useful or fast.

What you have to do is to create a separate node for the users attending a given event. You can name it something like `UsersAttendingTheEvent`. This will have the event keys as children. Whenever a user starts attending a given event, add the user key as a child of the event key ( and thus, grandchild of `UsersAttendingTheEvent`.

So, for example,

```
UsersAttendingTheEvent:{
 -KntTJCVBtbrb79dHemC:{
        rPxwIzEtJaRbEH6ujkP5QJgpHDp2: true
        MtaPwHEKMEOTXBRdXBuXuS3gst12: false
       }}
```

Now, when you want to run a query, you can just run a simple `orderByChild(userId)` query on `UsersAttendingTheEvent` to obtain all the keys of the events that the user is attending.

Following this, you can obtain the Event details from your main `event/eventKey`. This might seem like an additional call, but it is how denormalisation of data is designed for Firebase. Plus, it works reasonably fast.

**EDIT**

The reason your `startAt(true`) and `endAt(false)` returned nothing is that when `orderByChild()` is called, the order in which the items returned are as follows:-

1. null
2. false
3. true
4. numerically
5. lexicographically

This is mentioned on this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data.

Try using only `startAt(true)`. This would work if you make sure that your member keys only have true or false values and no other value would be returned lexicographically after `true`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already have this all denormalized and was just seeing if this was possible to avoid the 2 step process of getting the key and then getting the actual object, but thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's good then. Maybe there is a way for you to do that. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Great answer Rohan. @Roberto: Your current structure makes it easy to show the list of users for each events. But if you want to show a list of events for each user, you should (also) store the list of events for each user.  This type of data duplication is quite normal on Firebase Database (and many other NoSQL solutions). I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen. It's an honor just being noticed by you!

Comment: Rohan, I somehow missed the update. That's good info, but then I figure startAt(false) and endAt(true) should work for what I want and as I remember that didn't work either. Maybe I just got switched around. I'll double-check when I can. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertoCuba startAt(false) and endAt(true) will not work! This will return all the children which have false as the property value. You see, `endAt(true)` means that you'll obtain all children with property values that come before the ones with property value as true. It does not include the ones with true as the property. So, if you want to retrieve the ones with true, then please do follow the method in the answer's update, which is `startAt(true)`.